# Understand the code of Tab activity. What's the relationship between PagerAdapter and Placeholder

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I created a Tabbed Activity from AS template. It automatically creates some codes include:

**ui.main folder:**

- PageViewModule
- PlaceholderFragment
- SectionsPage
- MainActivity

**java folder:**

- MainActivity.java

**Layout.java**

- activity_mainxml
- fragment_main.xml

I am following a tutorial video and it is very different from what I saw in the AS.

I understood that activity_main contains the Action bar which includes the tab layout and a ViewPager which can display the Fragment through the `SectionsPagerAdapter.java`.

What I didn't understand is the code between the Placeholder, SectionsPagerAdapter, and PageViewModel. I put some comments in my code which is my confusing point.

SectionPagerAdapter.java

```java
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // Trying to use this to create the different Fragment but it doesn't work.
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                return new Fragment1();
            case 1:
                return new Fragment2();
            case 2:
                return new Fragment3();
        }
        return null;

        // return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }
```

PlaceholderFragment.java

```java
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private PageViewModel pageViewModel;

// Use PlaceholderFragment to display the Fragment selected by 
// SectionPageAdapter
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int index) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();

        //why we need to create a BUNDLE here?
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, index);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    // What's the function of onCreate? 
    // Why we need PageViewModel?
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pageViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PageViewModel.class);
        int index = 1;
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            index = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
        }
        pageViewModel.setIndex(index);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // To create the Fragment. In here it is only Fragment1 
        // That's the reason why it can only display the same Fragment?
        // How to make it associate with different Fragment?
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

        // Change the textView in the `fragment_main.xml` based on the 
        // different tab you chose. 
        // Example: Tab 1 --> textView" You selected Tab1"
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        pageViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
```

PageViewModel.java

```java
private MutableLiveData<Integer> mIndex = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private LiveData<String> mText = Transformations.map(mIndex, new Function<Integer, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(Integer input) {
            return "Hello world from section: " + input;
        }
    });

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        mIndex.setValue(index);
    }

    public LiveData<String> getText() {
        return mText;
    }
```

Is there anyone can help to explain how to associate Fragment with SectionsPager and how to use Placeholder to display the Fragment in the ViewPager? This is almost 80% different from the video I watched.

Answer (score 0):

i know this late answer, but in case you still need an answer,

to add new fragment to sectionsPager, you need to add different title like below in SectionPagerAdapter too,

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

@StringRes
private static final int[] TAB_TITLES = new int[]{R.string.tab_text_1, R.string.tab_text_2, R.string.tab_text_3};
private final Context mContext;
```

change the number in getCount in sectionspageradapter.java as your number of fragments,

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
```

then add tabe name to your strings.xml

```
<string name="tab_text_1">Fragment 1</string>
<string name="tab_text_2">Fragment 2</string>
<string name="tab_text_3">Fragment 3</string>
```

and create 3 different class and 3 different layout xml for every fragment